# Self signed IdentityServer certificate not working on macos Monterey

Tags: macos, ssl, identityserver4

I have IdentityServer4 on macos. Idv has self signed certificate on localhost. It have worked till was updated macos to Monterey.
Not working Safari, Chrome, Firefox. Safari stucks with blank page, Chrome shows error ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

[image]

This certificate have worked from June without any problems till Monterey.

What I tried to do:

1. created new certificate with 4096 key size.
2. created new certificate with expires in 720 days.

But always I got same problem.

openssl version: libreSSL 3.4.1

And I tried create with [dotnet dev-certs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it be that the server only provides out of date / old SSL protocols (like TLS 1.0 or SSL 2/3).  Try to scan your service using the [SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) at SSLLabs.

Also, HTTPS certificates should have 398 as the maximum life time. See this article for details:

- [398-Day Browser Limit for SSL/TLS Certificates Begins September 1, 2020](https://www.ssl.com/blogs/398-day-browser-limit-for-ssl-tls-certificates-begins-september-1-2020/)

In general I think using 2048 keys enough for most applications.